# Make index entries refer to something other than the page numbers

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

For a given book which is a daily devotional, I have no page numbers at all, but each section corresponds to a day in the year, with one day per page. I generate an index of Bible references in the end of the book, and I link the Bible references to the page where they are quoted. But since there are no page numbers in the book, the index must contain the day (i.e. the secion, e.g. "13 Mai" instead of 151) instead of the page number.

So far, my (ugly) solution was to output the section name and page in the logs with:

```
 \typeout{Date on page \thepage:\thesection:\chaphead}%
```

and then use a shell script to parse the logs and modify the generated index (.ind file) with sed:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     

NAME="$1"                                                                       

while read -r page day month; do                                                
   bsmonth=$(sed -e 's@\\@\\\\@g' <<<$month)                                    
   sed -i "s@textrm{\([^,]*, \)\?$page\(, [^,]*\)\?}@textrm{\1\\\\hyperlink{page.$page}{\\\\mbox{\\\\scshape\\\\makedate{$day}~$bsmonth}}\2}@g" $NAME.ind
done < <(sed -n 's@Date on page \([0-9]\+\):\([0-9]\+\):\(.*\)@\1 \2 \3@p' $NAME.log)
```

I would call LaTeX this way:

```
%.pdf: %.tex            
    TEXINPUTS=$(TEXINPUTS) pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=batchmode $< 
    # Modify index to use dates instead of pages                            
    ./index_dates.sh $*                                                     
    # No -shell-escape to prevent re-creation of index                      
    TEXINPUTS=$(TEXINPUTS) pdflatex -interaction=batchmode $<
```

I'm using `imakeidx` so the index is automatically regenerated when I compile the document. In TeXLive 2009, not passing `-shell-escape` prevented `imakeidx` from rebuilding the index, and thus from erasing the changes made by `index_dates.sh`, so it worked fine (although still ugly).

Now in TeXLive 2010, the `-shell-escape` trick doesn't work, and before I switch to another ugly trick, I'd like to think of rewriting this piece of code in proper TeX. Can you give me some hint as to how to do it properly?

- Should I generate dynamic macros such as:

  ```
  \def\pagemonth@\csname \thepage{\thesection~\chaphead}
  ```

and then modify the index? If so, how do I modify the index?

- Should I write these macros to a separate file and import it later on (and how to do that)?
- Should I hook into `imakeidx` (and how)?
- Should I replace `imakeidx` with another package that would allow this more easily?
- Should I switch to another index builder (such as `xindy`) and what parameters would I pass it?
- Should I add a "style" for page numbers in the index which would actually be a call to a macro replacing with my content?

Comment: I would title this question something like: "Can index entries (from makeindex) refer to something other than the page numbers?" to make it clearer what you are trying to achieve (the shell script is incidental to the problem, it seems).

Comment: @Andrew: ack, done.

Comment: it's a **glossaries** job, I believe.

Comment: @egreg: the thing is, I'm not generating the index myself, the `bibleref` package with the `ibibleverse` command calls `index`. Can `glossaries` interface with that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. I show it with sections, it should be easy to adapt to your setting.

(1) I define a counter and step it each time a new section is started with the `\Section` command, which defines a unique command holding the section's title and whose name depends on the value of the counter.

(2) I get copies of the relevant indexing commands and patch them: `\Index` requires `\@Index` which in turn requires `\@Wrindex`; `\@Wrindex` is the heart of the process, because it writes the entry in the `.idx` file. So I patch it in such a way that it *immediately* writes the current value of the counter. Here `\protected@iwrite` is the same as `\protected@write`, but does an `\immediate\write` instead of the usual delayed `\write`, since we don't need the page number which is known only during the output routine.

(3) The real `\Index` command is a wrapper around a useful function of **makeindex**, usually employed for "See…".

(4) We pass **makeindex** the `-s raphink` option, where `raphink.ist` is a style file containing only

```
delim_0 ""
```

that will not add a comma after an entry.

Now a command such as `\Index{Veni Sancte Spiritus}` in the "January 1st" section will write

```
\indexentry{Veni Sancte Spiritus|transform}{1}
```

in the `.idx` file (assuming that 1 is the current value of the counter). If we write also `\Index{Veni Sancte Spiritus}` on Pentecost, we'll have an entry such as

```
\indexentry{Veni Sancte Spiritus|transform}{150}
```

Processing with `makeindex -s raphink` (done automatically by **imakeidx**) will give the following in the `.ind` file:

```
\item Veni Sancte Spiritus \transform{1, 150}
```

The macro `\transform` reads the comma separated list and splits it using then the commands `\csname cursec1\endcsname` and `\csname cursec150\endcsname` that contain the correct section titles.

## The implementation

Here are the macros in a sample document.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{raphink.ist}
delim_0 ""
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{indexcnt}
\newcommand\Section[1]{%
  \stepcounter{indexcnt}%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname cursec\theindexcnt\endcsname{#1}%
  \section{#1}}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options=-s raphink]

\makeatletter
\let\@Index\@index
\patchcmd{\@Index}{\@wrindex}{\@Wrindex}{}{}
\let\@Wrindex\@wrindex
\patchcmd{\@Wrindex}{\thepage}{\theindexcnt}{}{}
\let\xIndex\index
\patchcmd{\xIndex}{\@index}{\@Index}{}{}
\patchcmd{\xIndex}{\@index}{\@Index}{}{}
\let\protected@iwrite\protected@write
\patchcmd{\protected@iwrite}{\write}{\immediate\write}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@Wrindex}{\protected@write}{\protected@iwrite}{}{}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\Index}[1]{\xIndex{#1|transform}}
\newcommand{\transform}[1]{\forcsvlist\decodesec{#1}}
\newcommand{\decodesec}[1]{, \csname cursec#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Christmas}

\Section{January 1st}

...
Veni Sancte Spiritus\Index{Veni Sancte Spiritus}
...

\chapter{Easter}

\Section{Pentecost}

...
Veni Sancte Spiritus\Index{Veni Sancte Spiritus}
...


\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Raphink A line was missing, try now.

Comment: @egreg: ok the example works now, but I can't adapt it to my needs somehow... I'm trying `\renewcommand*{\biblerefindex}[1]{\xIndex{#1|transform}}` since `bibleref.sty` has `\newcommand*{\biblerefindex}{\index}`...

Comment: My bad, patching a command *before* defining it is a **bad** idea ;-)

Comment: @Raphink: definitely. `:-)` Let me know about the result.

Comment: There is something I don't understand... I have `\expandafter\gdef\csname pagedate\thepage\endcsname{\pagedate}%` when a section is triggered. I expect the **value** of `\pagedate` to be stored in the `\pagedate234` macro (as an example), but it seems `\pagedate` is executed when the macro is called. How can I store the **value** of `\pagedate` instead of the **definition** of the macro?

Comment: @Raphink: use `\xdef` instead of `\gdef`, that is, `\global\edef` instead of `\global\def`.

Comment: @egreg: Great, I tried to find this one for quite some time (I tried `egdef`, `gedef`...). Now the problem is that all entries have a `,` before them, while only the second and following should have one...

Comment: @egreg: Alright, I fixed that with a simple `ifthenelse` on a flag. I'll accept your answer, and I'll post mine for the record.

Comment: I just used this again. I wish I could vote more than once :-) It would be nice to provide a command in `imakeidx` to allow mapping index to a custom counter instead of `\thepage`. This is especially useful in ebooks, where pages don't make sense.

Comment: @Raphink I'll think about this.

Comment: Great, thank you @egreg. For the record, this is the kind of usage I've had lately: https://github.com/cc-translators/charismanie/blob/master/charismanie.4ht#L49

Comment: Hello @egreg, thank you for this piece of code... It looked like magic at first, but I think I have understood now!
I have a remaining question : I would like to display the counter number instead of its name... I have tried this, but unfortunately it does not work : it displays the same number over and over. Do you have any idea ?

\expandafter\gdef\csname cursec\theindexcnt\endcsname{\theindexcnt}

Answer (score 3):

Here is my final implementation of @egreg's answer. It uses `\thepage` in spite of his idea to use a counter. The reason for that is that I want to generate hyperlinks in the index, which is not possible if I don't know the page to link to, and I don't want to play with hundreds of dynamic labels. All in all, this works and I'm happy with it:

```
\newcommand{\getpagedate}[1]{%                                                  
  \csname pagedate#1\endcsname                                                  
}                                                                               

\usepackage{etoolbox}                                                           
\newcommand{\transform}[1]{                                                     
  \def\secondparam{0}%                                                          
  \forcsvlist\decodesec{#1}}                                                    
\newcommand{\decodesec}[1]{%                                                    
  \ifthenelse{\secondparam=1}{, }{}%                                            
  \hyperlink{page.#1}{\mbox{\scshape\getpagedate{#1}}}%                         
  \def\secondparam{1}}                                                          
\renewcommand*{\bvidxpgformat}{transform} 

\newcommand{\dvday}[1]{\newpage\section{#1}%                                   
  \expandafter\xdef\csname pagedate\thepage\endcsname{\noexpand\makedate{\thesection}~\chaphead}%                                                                         
}
```

And here is a picture of the result:

[image: index with dates]