# How to make index entries refer to section numbers and/or figure/table numbers, and replace comma with leaders?

Tags: indexing

One could use the package makeidx together with the program makeindex to generate index table in his/her LaTeX document, automatically. They are great tools, however, I'm not satisfied with the default outputting style.

The default style uses a comma as separative sign of index entry name and the page number(s), and what I need is something like the default table of contents --- using leaders as separator  and referring to the section numbers (but not page number).

I've searched and read lots of posts on Internet, and [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20894/make-index-entries-refer-to-something-other-than-the-page-numbers) seems to be the answer to the question. However, I don't know how to migrate them into my document. For these reasons, could I ask for a step by step answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use section numbers instead of page numbers it is necessary to redefine the way, the index entry is written to `\jobname.idx`. That is basically easy, if the package `imakeidx` is used.

In its manual, `imakeidx` the author writes, that `\imki@wrindexentry` should be redefined to apply for other styles. Looking into the package, there is a similar command used with `\thepage` as argument, so redefined it, using `\thesection`.

However, `makeindex` as external processor complains about the new format if `\thesection` writes its numbers as `1.1` etc., i.e. with dots. Using `xindy` solves this problem, by applying a new alphabet or location-class, this is done in `sectionindex_xindy.xdy`, as well as removing the `,` separator and inserting `-----` instead.

**Content of `sectionindex_xindy.xdy`**

```
(markup-locclass-list :open " ----- " :sep "")

( define-location-class "numericsections"
                        ("arabic-numbers" :sep "." "arabic-numbers"))

( define-location-class "numericchapteralphasections"
                        ("arabic-numbers" :sep "." "ALPHA"))
```

---

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}

%\usepackage{hyperref}% Leads to linking to wrong positions%





\makeatletter
% Global redefinition of indexentry to section instead of page%
\renewcommand{\imki@wrindexentrysplit}[3]{%
 \expandafter\protected@write\csname#1@idxfile\endcsname{}%
    {\string\indexentry{#2}{\thesection}}%
}%


\LetLtxMacro{\LaTeXStandardFigure}{\figure}
\let\LaTeXStandardEndFigure\endfigure%

\renewenvironment{figure}[1][tpb]{%
%redefine the index write command to use figure number instead of section number
\renewcommand{\imki@wrindexentrysplit}[3]{%
\expandafter\protected@write\csname##1@idxfile\endcsname{}%
    {\string\indexentry{##2}{\thefigure}}
}%
\LaTeXStandardFigure[#1]%
}{%
\LaTeXStandardEndFigure%
}%

\LetLtxMacro{\LaTeXStandardTable}{\table}
\let\LaTeXStandardEndTable\endtable%



\renewenvironment{table}[1][tpb]{%
%redefine the index write command to use table number instead of section number
\renewcommand{\imki@wrindexentrysplit}[3]{%
\expandafter\protected@write\csname##1@idxfile\endcsname{}%
    {\string\indexentry{##2}{\thetable}}
}%
\LaTeXStandardTable[#1]%
}{%
\LaTeXStandardEndTable%
}%

\makeatother

\makeindex[options=-M sectionindex_xindy.xdy]

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}%
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\Alph{section}}%
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}%

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{First}

\begin{figure}
\caption{A first figure with index entry, say Figure\index{Figure!First}}
\end{figure}


\section{First section of chapter~\arabic{chapter}}

Here is a table (well, the environment actually)

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
A & dummy & table \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{A table with some index entry in it: \index{Table}{First}}
\end{table}
See also the keyword Index\index{Index}

\chapter{Two}

\section{First}
Index\index{Index} and its usage\index{usage}

\begin{figure}
\caption{A dummy figure with an index entry, say DummyFigure\index{Figure!DummyFigure}}

\end{figure}


\printindex


\end{document}
```

In order to make this work for figures/tables, I just redefined the command again within wrappers for `figure` and `table` environment. You have redefine `\thefigure` and `\thetable` explicitly, since it seems, that they introduce a trailing `\relax` command just before the figure/table number.

Please note, that this does not work correctly with hyperlinks so far,regarding the figure/table index entries.

Enabling **--shell-escape** is mandatory.

[image]

Comment: Hello @Hupfer! Thank you for your answer, the result of your codes is almost what I need. However, by `leaders` in the question, I mean a series of `$\cdot$`, but not `-----`, and not dividing into two columns is necessary. For these two reasons, I'd like to replace `-----`, in the file `sectionindex_xindy.xdy`, with `\xleaders\hbox{$\cdot$}\hfill`, and to add `columns = 1` into the options list of command `\makeindex`. Now, everything works fine! Thank you again!

Comment: @HongyanLu: Nice that it was almost complete, but I was not sure about any issue of your request. I will change my provided solution later on

Comment: Hello @Hupfer! I just got another solution and made a new answer to this question. I think that is a fantastic method, and hope you will enjoy it. :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, I find another solution that is more elegant than Hupfer's, from my point of view.

Since `makeindex(.exe)` could only handle positive number as page numbers, and would complain about something like `1.1`, which is, in general, the form of subsection numbers, we have two choices: bypassing this obstruction by using other indexing program, such as `xindy` (which is described by Hupfer); encoding `1.1` in base-100 number system, i.e. `101`, before the `.idx` file is processed by `makeindex`, and modifying the `.ind` file before being loaded by `\printindex`.

To achieve this, I mean, the second choice, I borrowed some code from [LeoLiu@bbs.ctex.com](http://bbs.ctex.org/forum.php?mod=redirect&goto=findpost&ptid=78544&pid=459853&fromuid=162254) and [egreg@tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20910/38350). And finally, I got the following:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{indexsec.ist}
preamble = "\begin{theindex}\def\seename{See}\def\alsoname{Also see}\providecommand*\indexgroup[1]{\indexspace\item \textbf{#1}\nopagebreak}"

postamble "\n\n\\end{theindex}\n"

group_skip "\n\n  \\indexspace\n\n"


delim_0 "\\xleaders\\hbox{$\\cdot$}\\hfill "
delim_1 "\\xleaders\\hbox{$\\cdot$}\\hfill "
delim_2 "\\xleaders\\hbox{$\\cdot$}\\hfill "

headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\mbox{}\\hfill{}\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}\\hfill\\mbox{}"

numhead_positive "Number"
numhead_negative "Number"
symhead_positive "Symbol"
symhead_negative "Symbol"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options = -s indexsec.ist, columns = 1]

\makeatletter
\def\idx@encode#1#2{%
  \the\numexpr#1 * 100 + #2\relax}
\newcount\idx@low
\newcount\idx@high
\def\idx@decode#1{%
  \idx@high=#1
  \divide\idx@high by 100
  \idx@low=\numexpr#1-100*\idx@high\relax}

\def\subsecindexpage#1{%
  \idx@decode{#1}%
  \the\idx@high.\the\idx@low}

\let\idx@wrindex@subsec\@wrindex
\patchcmd\idx@wrindex@subsec
  {\thepage}
  {\idx@encode{\arabic{section}}{\arabic{subsection}}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd\idx@wrindex@subsec
  {#2}
  {#2|subsecindexpage}
  {}{}

\newcommand\subsecindex[1][\imki@jobname]{%
  \@bsphack
    \@ifundefined{#1@idxfile}%
    {\PackageWarning{imakeidx}{Undefined index file `#1'}%
    \begingroup
    \@sanitize
    \imki@nowrindex}%
    {\edef\@idxfile{#1}%
     \begingroup
     \@sanitize
     \idx@wrindex@subsec\@idxfile}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}

foo, bar, baz
\subsecindex{foo}\subsecindex{bar}\subsecindex{baz}

\subsection{Hoge}

hoge, fuga, piyo
\subsecindex{hoge}\subsecindex{fuga}\subsecindex{piyo}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

BTW, in this case, enabling `--shell-escape` is mandatory, too.

Comment: A nice idea, but what if there are 100 or more figures/tables in a chapter ( a rare case, admitted ;-)) A little example: Say, the `thefigure` is provideds `1.100`, so this would lead to `1*100 + 100 = 200`, divided by 100, finally resulting in `2`, all done by `\idx@encode` and `\idx@decode`, leaving a index 'page reference' to `2.0`

Comment: @Hupfer: Yeah, you got it. That's the very limitation of the solution. However, no proper remedy comes into my mind. Sadly. :(