# Cannot make index referring to line numbers list more than one instance

Tags: indexing, line-numbering, imakeidx, xpatch

I cannot wrap my head around the existing examples like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20894/make-index-entries-refer-to-something-other-than-the-page-numbers?noredirect=1&lq=1).

I am using the `ekdosis` package, which depends on the `verse`, and ultimately `lineno` to generate line numbers for a long verse based document. Now I was helped out with the following command, but I cannot get the right result, which should read "rose, 1, 4, 8". I am getting "rose, 8" instead:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{ekdosis}

\makeindex

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lineindex}[1]{\linelabel{#1}\index{#1}}
\patchcmd{\@wrindex}{\thepage}{\getrefnumber{#2}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{ekdosis}
\begin{ekdverse}
The rose is a rose,\lineindex{rose} \\*
And was always a rose. \\*
But the theory now goes \\*
That the apple's a rose,\lineindex{rose} \\*
And the pear is, and so's \\*
The plum, I suppose. \\*
The dear only knows \\*
What will next prove a rose.\lineindex{rose} \\*
You, of course, are a rose - \\*
But were always a rose.\\*
Robert Frost\\*
\end{ekdverse}
\end{ekdosis}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thanks! I'm carrying one indexing with the assumption that the problem will get solved here ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ekdosis` is loaded with `[poetry=verse]`, like so: `\usepackage[poetry=verse]{ekdosis}`, this should work:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[poetry=verse]{ekdosis}

\makeindex

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@wrindex}{\thepage}{\thepoemline}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{ekdosis}
  \begin{ekdverse}
    The rose is a rose,\index{rose} \\*
    And was always a rose. \\*
    But the theory now goes \\*
    That the apple's a rose,\index{rose} \\*
    And the pear is, and so's \\*
    The plum, I suppose. \\*
    The dear only knows \\*
    What will next prove a rose.\index{rose} \\*
    You, of course, are a rose - \\*
    But were always a rose.\\*
    Robert Frost\\*
  \end{ekdverse}
\end{ekdosis}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again, Robert!